# MS SQL Delete records older than month

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

I have data stored in ms sql database. I want delete all records older than some date. 
For this, a service is used that sends a request once a day, like:

`delete from [log].[HttpRequestLogEntries] where DateTimeUtc < dateadd(day, -3, getutcdate())`

and it work fine, but very slowly. In my table can be over 10kk rows and deleting may take hours for the work.
How to solve this problem in the best way?

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes it's faster to delete in small loops rather than all in one go, as Paul mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is not an existing index with a first column of [DateTimeUtc], you might try adding one.  Indexing the column in the search criteria has improved mass delete performance on some of our databases.  The trade-off is that inserts and updates may take additional time to maintain index entries.

Consider deleting fewer rows at a time.  If you delete more than 5,000 rows at once, the delete query may attempt to [escalate to a table lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms184286(v=sql.105)).  If there is a lot of concurrent activity, the attempt to acquire a table lock may block while other requests complete.

For example, this loop deletes 4,000 rows maximum at a time:

```
declare @RowCount int = 1
while @RowCount > 0
begin
    delete top (4000)
    from [log].[HttpRequestLogEntries]
    where DateTimeUtc < dateadd(day, -3, getutcdate())

    select @RowCount = @@rowcount
end
```

Also, check for database triggers.  If a trigger is firing when rows are deleted, it is possible code in the trigger is causing a long delay.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Want to clarify one point.

If I have a nonclustered composite index of the form
 IX_[TableName]_[Column1]_[Column2]_[DateTimeUtc] then when a query with a condition only on DateTimeUtc, it does not work, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  In your case, the only query criteria is a date range using the `DateTimeUtc` column.  If the first column of the index is not `DateTimeUtc`, then the query cannot use it.  The query will do a table scan (possibly scanning this index) to find all matching rows.  If the query search criteria was `where [Column1] = 'value1' and [Column2] = 'value2' and DateTimeUtc < [DateLogic]`, then the query would be able to use the index.